# How to account for ticklabelsize in figsize in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create figures in Matplotlib for an academic paper, and I want to make sure the images are consistent in shape, size, and fontsize. I am compositing my images in Microsoft PowerPoint.

One of my biggest problems is getting panels in my figure to look consistent. I want my Overleaf document to have pt size 8 ticklabels so it is easy to read everything. However, I only have a width of 3.5 inches on my paper.

In matplotlib, if I set figsize to (1.7, 1.7), it tries to fit ticklabels and the canvas into the 1.7x1.7 box. **How do I make it such that my canvas is 1.7x1.7, and the ticklabels are on the exterior of fontsize 8?** Furthermore, I also sometimes make barplots and I need to add a rotated ticklabel. **How do I make sure that the rotated labels are also right on the outside of the canvas and within the frame?** The rotated labels have a tendency to get cut out.

Any advice you have will be appreciated!

Comment: Does adding `plt.tight_layout()` help with the cut off labels?

Comment: Also, please share a minimal reproducible example.